# How to drag and stop panel before some line in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, draggable, panel, drag

I'm trying drag my panel and stop my panel before some line.  I don't know how to do this.
Let I explain with my code(it's not working):

```
//MyPanel
<s:Panel                                                                         
  mouseMove="rectangle_mouseMoveHandler(event)"
  width="30" height="30" id="panel" backgroundAlpha="0.2" 
  mouseDown="onMouseDown(event)" mouseUp="onMouseUp(event)"                              
  skinClass="intetech.PanelNoTitleBar" backgroundColor="blue">                                                      
</s:Panel>


//rectangle_mouseMoveHandler
protected function rectangle_mouseMoveHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
    {

        if ((panel.x+panel.width)>=(minimap.x+minimap.width)){
            panel.x = (minimap.x+minimap.width-panel.width+0.001);              
        }
        trace("panel.x = "+panel.x);
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working?"  Is the panel dragging past the point that you'd like it to stop?  This is a strange drag handler.  You might do a little more research or think through the problem more carefully.  I'm guessing that every time you move your mouse, it bumps the panel to the right a little bit independent of how you moved the mouse.

Comment: @NTyler Yes, the panel dragging past the point. I don't know how to stop my panel

Comment: Is the dragging otherwise working like you expect it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bounds relative to the coordinates of the Sprite's parent that specify a constraint rectangle for the Sprite:

```
protected function panel_mouseUpHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    panel.stopDrag();
}

protected function panel_mouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    panel.startDrag(false, new Rectangle( 0,0, 500, 300));
}

//...

<s:Panel id="panel" width="300" height="200" mouseUp="panel_mouseUpHandler(event)" mouseDown="panel_mouseDownHandler(event)"/>
```